# ReactJs/NextJs useEffect() always called two times

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect

My useEffect() hook is **always called twice**. There are two dependencies: reinitializePage (when set to true, useEffect will be called), and corporateContext (when context changes, component should be updated).

```
const [reinitializePage, setReinitializePage] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if (reinitializePage === true || corporateContext) {
      (async () => { ... })();
      setReinitializePage(false);
  }
}, [reinitializePage, corporateContext]);
```

- I understand why it always triggers twice.
- **By default reinitializePage is set to true so useEffect will trigger**, after change to false, as reinitializePage is a dependancy, it will trigger again and since there is "or" condition in if statement and corporateContext is always populated, it will trigger again. If I dont add corporateContext to if condition then when context changes it wont trigger useEffect because reinitializePage is set to false. I cannot add "&&" condition in if statement because these two dependencies are not following each other.

So how can I ensure that when first trigger is happened and when reinitializePage is set to false inside useEffect, how to ensure that after reinitalize page change from true to false, dont trigger it again.

Comment: useEffect does not trigger depending on your `if` statement, it triggers when it's dependencies - in your case `reinitializePage` and `corporateContext`- change. If you do not want the async function to trigger if `renitializePage` is false just use `&&` in your if statement.

Comment: Hi, I know that it  triggers when one of dependencies changes. And main problem is that it triggers when reinitializePage is set to false under useEffect method and right after that it will trigger again. I cannot set it to && because there is also possibility that reinitializePage is set to false and corporateContext is changed.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. The problem was **StrictMode**.

For NextJS set reactStrictMode to false:

```
// next.config.js
   module.exports = {
     reactStrictMode: false, // ← this
   }
```

For React remove the StrictMode block:

```
<StrictMode> 
  <App />
</StrictMode>
```

For details: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/StrictMode

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple useEffect:

```
const [reinitializePage, setReinitializePage] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if (reinitializePage === true) {
      (async () => { ... })();
      setReinitializePage(false);
  }
}, [reinitializePage]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (corporateContext) {
      (async () => { ... })();
      setReinitializePage(false);
  }
}, [corporateContext]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can store `reinitializePage` in `useRef`:

```js
const reinitializePageRef = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if (reinitializePageRef.current === true || corporateContext) {
      (async () => { ... })();

      reinitializePageRef.current = false;
  }
}, [corporateContext]);
```

In this case `useEffect` wouldn't update if `reinitializePageRef` is changed, so if you set this value somewhere else, it might not work.